# substitute word boundaries with vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace, sed

I would like to transform object attribute references into array ones like this:

> $stuff->a_property

into

> $stuff['a_property']

I've tried

```
s/->.*\>/['\0'\]/g
```

but it gives me

> $stuff['->a_property']

Comment: Can you be a little clearer? Are you trying to replace the `>` with `['` while adding `']` at the end? I don't see any need for regex to do this, however I am unfamiliar with "vim" or "sed" so I may be wrong.

Comment: `->word` into `['word']`    Why do you thing there's no need for regex, how would you do it?

Comment: Because it sounds like what you are wanting is to REPLACE/ALTER your original string. Regular Expression is used to search and capture specific sections of a string. This captured information can in turn be used to replace and alter the string yes, but outside of regex. RegExp can not alter your string in any way, only return a section of the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **captured group**:

```
:%s/->\(.*\)\>/['\1'\]/
```

`\(.*\)` is used for capturing value after `->` into group #1 being used in replacement. This will give you `$stuff['a_property']`

**EDIT:** If you want to do multiple replacements per line then use:

```
:%s/->\(.\{-}\)\>/['\1'\]/g
```

`.\{-}` is for non-greedy match whereas `.*` is greedy.

Comment: `g` is too much but still +1

Comment: That's right, I updated further to use a non-greedy match in case multiple replacements are to be done on same line.

Comment: for multiline replacement you could add the option `%`  (`:%s`) in addition to multi occurence of `g`

Comment: Yes indeed. I was always testing with `:%s/...`

Answer (score 1):

The regex in your expression matches `->` and later substitutes the whole match inside `[]`. That's why you get

```
$stuff['->a_property']
```

@anubhava already posted an answer, however I would propose another, perhaps more readable variant, using the `\v` operator:

```
:s/\v\-\>(.*)>/['\1']/g
```

`\v` means "treat all subsequent characters in the pattern, excluding `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z` and `_`, as special". For more info, see `:help /\v`.

Answer (score 1):

```
:s/->\zs.*\>/['\0'\]/g
```

works too, be excluding `->` from the text that goes into `\0`.